# How to stop username enumeration in Samba on Ubuntu?

Tags: security, samba

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to serve a web application to a local Windows network. A recent pen test highlighted that it was possible to enumerate local user accounts on the Samba service. I have been asked to disable this. This isn't something I've encountered before and I can't find the relevant documentation. The only lines in my `smb.conf` relating to enumeration are commented out. I include them below for reference anyway.

```
winbind enum groups = yes
winbind enum users = yes
```

How do I disable anonymous account enumeration? Is doing so likely to have undesirable side effects?

Answer (score 0):

Local enumeration isn't done by samba, it's done by the local system. and no, you cannot disable it in samba. Winbind enumeration is already disabled, if these lines are commented out. But this disables only the enumeration of external usernames.